# Concatenation issues

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table "Patient" which has 5 fields.

```
CREATE TABLE PATIENT
(PAT_ID         CHAR (4) PRIMARY KEY,
 PAT_NAME       VARCHAR (7),
 ADMITTED       DATE,
 ROOM           CHAR (3),
 DOCTOR         VARCHAR (7));

INSERT INTO PATIENT VALUES
(1001, 'FRED', '30-MAR-07', 101, 'PAYNE');
```

I want to create a view where my output to look like this:

```
Patient      Doctor       Room         Admitted    
"-----------------------------------------------"
1001 Fred    Payne        101      March 31, 2007
```

The problem is that I want to concatenate Pat_name and Pat_ID into their own separate "Patient" column but ALSO have the other three fields also concatenated with it (notice there is no separation in the 'dashes').

Basically, I want one single column with all 5 columns concatenated, but I need to also have the first two columns combined into a single subcolumn named "patient".

Can you concatenate within a concatenation?

Comment: I tried this: 
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW PATIENT_REPORT 
AS SELECT
 (SELECT PATIENT.PAT_ID||' '||PATIENT.PAT_NAME as "patient" from Patient)||' '|| DOCTOR ||' '|| ROOM ||' '|| ADMITTED
FROM PATIENT; 
 
But I get a "Must name this expression with a column alias" error

Comment: I'm not sure exactly which fields you want to concatenate, but MySQL's `CONCAT` function can take any number of strings: `SELECT CONCAT('a','b','cc');` or `SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ','a','b','cc');`

Comment: Think of it like this.  I have 5 fields: 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5.  I need fields 1 and 2 combined and labeled as "Patient".  Then I need THAT column combined with fields 3, 4, and 5, which retain their own field names.  Look at what I listed as the output.  I'm basically taking 5 columns and combining them TWICE to produce one column with 4 labels yet 5 pieces of data

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CONCAT(PAT_ID, ' ', PAT_NAME) AS Patient,
    DOCTOR AS Doctor, ROOM AS Room, ADMITTED AS Admitted
FROM PATIENT
```

Comment: That gives me an "Invalid number of arguments" error for the CONCAT part

Comment: @JoshuaPlyler are you sure that this is MySQL?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure.  I'm still very new to this.  The program is called SQL*PLUS.  I didn't know there was a difference

Comment: @JoshuaPlyler SQL*PLUS is a client for Oracle Database, not MySQL (they're different applications which are "mostly" the same... this is one of the cases where they're not).

Comment: Ahh....so what can I do if I'm using SQL*PLUS to get 4 columns with 5 pieces of data?

Comment: @JoshuaPlyler I submitted a [separate answer referencing Oracle syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18411880/concantenation-issues/18412210#18412210).

Answer (score 0):

[It turns out you're actually using Oracle Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18411880/concantenation-issues#comment27046695_18411906). I'm still not sure exactly which fields you're trying to concatenate in which way, but this should be enough to get you rolling:

```
CREATE VIEW PATIENT_REPORT 
AS
SELECT
  PATIENT.PAT_ID||' '||PATIENT.PAT_NAME as "patient",
  PATIENT.DOCTOR||' '||PATIENT.ROOM||' '||PATIENT.ADMITTED as "details"
FROM PATIENT;
```

[Here's a live demo on SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4d74f/2)

Comment: This is close, but this still creates two separate columns, 'patient' and 'details'.  What I need is a single column with 4 separate labels and 5 bits of data.  Lol, I know it's confusing.

Comment: Why do you need exactly one column? If this data is being consumed by another application, return separate columns and let it worry about them. If this data is being read by people, who cares how many columns we have?

Comment: School project, just what the instructions are

Comment: @JoshuaPlyler May be something like demonstrated in [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e3cb11/5)?

Answer (score 0):

here is the query that creates view by name "view_name":

```
  create or replace view view_name as
select t.Pat_Id || ' ' || t.Pat_Name Patient,
       t.Doctor,
       t.Room,
       to_char(t.Admitted, 'Month dd, yyyy') Admitted
  from Patient t 
with read only;
```

you can select as

```
SELECT * FROM VIEW_NAME
```

I think that here provided enough information, that you can add or manipulate (other) columns wether to show.